# Android BLE onCharacteristicChanged not invoked

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my app I have used setCharacteristicNotification to enable notificaito for a characteristic. In the log cat i am getting notification enable true also got success on onDescriptorWrite callback but the callback method onCharacteristicChanged is not called.Please help me. thanks in advance

log

```
 D/BluetoothGatt(15694): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00003c01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
```

code

```
 mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
                    UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
           return mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Comment: Please help me. I am stuck in this issue.

Comment: Some thoughts that may help you. Check Bluetooth Profile implementation inside the bluetooth device,it either uses "Notification" or "Indication" for posting updates.Also some devices have control descriptors with certain bytes to activate notification flow, maybe the documentation has something about it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just added sleep between read and write operations and now it is working fine.

```
try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue, can you please help me with - where exactly should I add sleep?

Comment: This answer is inadequate. It does not explain what is meant by "read and write operations". Most people will think of the Bluetooth GATT callbacks for read and write, which cannot have any time between them because they are callbacks, not procedural code.